# Error on >pip wheel -w wheels -r packages.txt

Tags: python, python-venv

I want to port my python venv to another machine.
For that first I created a requirements.txt in my activated venv as

> pip freeze -l > packages.txt

As the PC I want to clone my venv to, don't have an internet connection, so I'm trying to create wheels of all packages as

> pip wheel -w wheels -r packages.txt`

But having this error during the creation wheels

[image]

And I think these lines in package.txt are creating problem

[image]

What these lines are doing with my github repo?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I attached the error screenshot

Comment: sudo -H pip3 install gitsome

Comment: what's that? I'm on Windows OS so pip3 and python3 will not work for me

Comment: @DevLoverUmar why not? If it's added in your env variables then it should work. Only thing that doesn't apply is the `sudo -H` bit. Please also post the error trace as text, It's such a cumbersome task to identify the error with the image.

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 Thanks man! It's done. You can post a simple answer describing the need of gitsome, so I can give you the due credit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user @AdamStrauss pointed out, performing

```
pip3 install gitsome
```

will solve the problem. This is due to the small drawback of `GitHub` workflow, i.e.

> Not all GitHub workflows work well in a terminal/CMD; gitsome attempts to target those that do.